# EF .FromSqlRaw call ending "500, An unhandled error occurred"

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

.netcore 3.1, EF 5.0, C#:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
  var r = _context.mymodel.FromSqlRaw<mytype>("[dbo].[test]");
  return Ok(r);
}
```

Breakpoint at `return Ok(r)` shows no **Exception**, but always

```
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "message": "An unhandled error occurred"
}
```

Adding `try...catch...`, it never steps into `catch`

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
  try {
    var r = ...
    return Ok(r);
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    return StatusCode(500, e.Message);  // <-- never reached.
  }
}
```

Also tried `public async Task<IActionResult> Get()` got same error.

How to identify the unhandled exception?

Comment: That likely returns a task and can’t be serialized

Comment: @DanielA.White Also tried `public async Task<IActionResult> Get()` got same error.

Comment: Did you try await on your sql call?

Comment: @Jeb50 what he meant is that your object cannot be serialized (`r`). Can you give us the detailed error message as well please? And what is the value of `r`?

Comment: Try adding `ToList` and see if the result is different: `return Ok(r.ToList());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues found and resolved:

1. A parameter is `guid` type, when passing in as a string, DebugView->Query, ran ok at SQL, but EF API fails no exception.
2. Two columns returned from SP sharing the same name in diff case, like `[orderid]` and `[ORDERID]` (from diff tables). SQL runs ok, not for EF, again no exception.

Answer (score 0):

I did some simple tests according to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) and didn't encounter your problem：

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
      try
      {
           var r = _context.mymodel.FromSqlRaw<mytype>("SELECT * FROM dbo.test");
           return Ok(r);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
           return StatusCode(500, e.Message);  
      }
}
```

Test Result:
[image]
[image]

What is your database structure and model like? Does `[dbo].[test]` match the fields in `_context.mymodel`?